# Is it possible to set the background color of a sector in a radar chart in Chart.js?

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, chart.js

I want to set the color of the sectors in my radar chart to look like this:

[image: Example]

Is this possible in Chart.js? Is there another chart package that can do it?

If it can work well with AngularJS that would be even better.

Comment: which version of chart.js you are using?

Comment: 1.1.1, because it works with angular-chart. But if I have to I'll upgrade to v2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer by Saurabh and also given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140652/chart-js-radar-chart-different-scalelinecolor-for-each-scaleline/33145267#33145267) won't work because filling the entire background will cover up the labels and give different areas for each sector.

So instead (in my case using [angular-chart](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js)) I prepend my dataset with data to match each sector, and passing a colour **object** I'm able to get it looking right as well.

So building the data in angular like this:

```
<canvas id="spider_chart" class="chart chart-base" chart-type="'Radar'"
        chart-data="angular_spider_chart.data"
        chart-options="angular_spider_chart.options"
        chart-labels="angular_spider_chart.labels"
        chart-series="angular_spider_chart.series"
        chart-colours="angular_spider_chart.colors">
</canvas>

<script>
    function makeList(n, v){
        // Make a list of data with n points all having v as value
        var x = [];
        for (; n>0; x[--n] = v);
        return x;
    }

    function getColour (colour) {
        // return colour object to override angular-chart getColour function
        return {
            fillColor: colour,
            strokeColor: colour,
            pointColor: colour,
            pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
            pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
            pointHighlightStroke: colour
        };
    }

    // build spider chart
    function initialize_spider_chart (chart_data, label){
        // the color you want to use in your dataset
        var colors = ["#000"];
        var labels = [];
        var data = [];
        var series = []
        // turn of animation otherwise "belts" animate
        var options =  {title: {display: true, text:label},
                scaleLineWidth :1,
                scaleShowLabels : false,
                pointDot : false,
                angleLineColor: "#e6e6e6",
                borderColor: "#737373",
                backgroundColor: '#cccccc',
                animation: false,
                showTooltips: false
            };
        // the sector values and colors of your backgrounds
        var belts = [[4, '#ef5350'], [3, '#ffaa00'], [2, '#00b19d'], [1, '#228bdf']];
        for (var idx in belts){
            var cp = belts[idx];
            data.push(makeList(chart_data.length, cp[0]));
            series.push("")
            colors.unshift(getColour(cp[1]))
        }
        var actual_data = [];
        for (var c in chart_data){
            labels.push(chart_data[c].name);
            actual_data.push(chart_data[c].value);
        }
        series.push('Banded Radar Chart');
        data.push(actual_data);
        return {'data': data,
                'labels': labels,
                'options': options,
                'colors': colors,
                'series': series
                };
    };
</script>
```

Gives me this:

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 1):

You can trick it by varying size of scaleline.

Try to set **scaleLineWidth** according to your requirement like this,

```
var radarOptions = {
    scaleLineWidth :16 ,
}
```

[**Check this fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/t0v6zjb6/2/)

Increase the **scaleLineWidth** till you fill the gap between 2 lines.

there you can set the **scaleLineColor** also, so that it will feel like a background,

```
var radarOptions = {
    scaleLineWidth :16 ,
    scaleLineColor : "#EEEEEE"
}
```

[**Check this fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/t0v6zjb6/3/)

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely on the right track. But then how would I make the different "scaleLines" different colors? In your second fiddle they are all the same color.

Comment: @Niel I haven't tried it in while, but for that purpose you have to go through a function where it is drawing a radar lines, i.e. scale lines and through each iteration, you have to set scaleLineColor. Meanwhile I will check for the better solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you meant, but I found a pretty neat solution. Would it be possible to draw 3 lines in the graph, each with the color you want the sector to be. Set the data values so they line each sector, and then set the line width to the sector width. Does that make sense, would it work?

Answer (score 0):

You may implement any radar diagram with any sectors you like using Chart.JS and its datasets property.

```
        "datasets": [
            {
                "backgroundColor": "rgba(94, 221, 46, 0)",
                "borderColor": "rgb(126, 255, 16)",
                "pointBackgroundColor": "#7eff10",
                "borderWidth": 2,
                "pointRadius": 4,
                "data": [
                    30,
                    62,
                    80,
                    30
                ]
            },
            {
                "backgroundColor": "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
                "pointRadius": 0,
                "borderWidth": 0,
                "data": [
                    9,
                    9,
                    9,
                    9
                ]
            },
            {
                "backgroundColor": "rgb(217, 217, 214)",
                "pointRadius": 0,
                "borderWidth": 0,
                "data": [
                    25,
                    25,
                    25,
                    25
                ]
            },
            {
                "backgroundColor": "rgb(113, 178, 201)",
                "pointRadius": 0,
                "borderWidth": 0,
                "data": [
                    50,
                    50,
                    50,
                    50
                ]
            },
            {
                "backgroundColor": "rgb(0, 119, 139)",
                "pointRadius": 0,
                "borderWidth": 0,
                "data": [
                    75,
                    75,
                    75,
                    75
                ]
            },
            {
                "backgroundColor": "rgb(0, 42, 58)",
                "pointRadius": 0,
                "borderWidth": 0,
                "data": [
                    100,
                    100,
                    100,
                    100
                ]
            },
            {
                "backgroundColor": "rgb(85, 89, 91)",
                "pointRadius": 0,
                "borderWidth": 2,
                "data": [
                    100,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0
                ]
            },
            {
                "backgroundColor": "rgb(85, 89, 91)",
                "pointRadius": 0,
                "borderWidth": 2,
                "data": [
                    0,
                    100,
                    0,
                    0
                ]
            },
            {
                "backgroundColor": "rgb(85, 89, 91)",
                "pointRadius": 0,
                "borderWidth": 2,
                "data": [
                    0,
                    0,
                    100,
                    0
                ]
            },
            {
                "backgroundColor": "rgb(85, 89, 91)",
                "pointRadius": 0,
                "borderWidth": 2,
                "data": [
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    100
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Checkout full version and how the chart looks like at my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rb38n490/5/