# Chart.js different scaleLine color of radar chart (angular)

Tags: angular, chart.js, styling, radar-chart

currently I am using radar-charts (chart.js) in my angular project. I' m want to change the scaleLineColor of the different section and don't know how to achieve this result:

[image]

according to this new fix it should be possible: 
https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/2732

I also tried this: [Chart.js (Radar Chart) different scaleLineColor for each scaleLine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140652/chart-js-radar-chart-different-scalelinecolor-for-each-scaleline)

but no effect at all ;( (I think because it's written in a older version)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the [gridlines](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html) `color` property to an array of the colours you want to use (emphasis mine):

> The color of the grid lines. ***If specified as an array, the first color applies to the first grid line, the second to the second grid line and so on.***

**Example:**

```js
var chart1 = new Chart(document.getElementById('chart'), {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'series1',
      data: [1, 2, 3, 6, 3, 2, 4]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scale: {
      gridLines: {
        color: ['black', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo']
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Note that you must use "angleLines" option to change the color of the lines between the center and the labels.

Comment: If someone stumbles upon this: v3 introduced some breaking changes to the configuration which make a migration necessary. The _options.scale.gridLines_  property for radar charts for example now is _options.scale.r.grid_. See https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.2.0/charts/radar.html and https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html#ticks

Comment: Excellent tip! But I believe it should read `options.scales.r.grid`

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this solution.
So in case anybody is seeing this now.

To clarify, Chart.js v3 and v4 syntax is [not backwards compatible](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) with Chart.js v2.

The radial different scale line color solution provided by @timclutton will work for Chart.js v2.

**Example as shown for v2:**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

```js
var chartv2 = new Chart(document.getElementById('chart'), {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {},
  options: {
    scale: {
      gridLines: {
        color: ['black', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo']
      }
    }
  }
});
```

To apply the same [grid line colors](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/#grid-lines) to v3 or v4:

**Example for v3 and v4:**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

```js
var chartv3 = new Chart(document.getElementById('chart'), {
    type: 'radar',
    data: {},
    options: {
        scales: {
            r: {
                grid: {
                    color: ['black', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo']
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```